# CLI: Get information Ubuntu releases

Tags: command-line, support

How can I get information about Ubuntu releases from the command line?
Items of interest

- Names vs. version numbers
- support state

Answer (score 8):

`ubuntu-distro-info` from the [distro-info [image: Install distro-info]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/distro-info) package provides information about **all** Ubuntu releases.

You get an overview of all releases with

```
ubuntu-distro-info --all --fullname
```

For the "current" version

```
ubuntu-distro-info --stable --fullname
```

For the current LTS release

```
ubuntu-distro-info --lts --fullname
```

For currently supported releases

```
ubuntu-distro-info --supported --fullname
```

(This strangely includes the current **development version** although it is not supported yet)

To get the number of days till EndOfLive you add `--days=eol` (shorter `-yeol`)

```
ubuntu-distro-info --supported --fullname --days=eol
```

To get the number of days till the current development version will be released you can use just `-y` or `--days`

```
ubuntu-distro-info --latest --fullname --days
```

Comment: The other useful command from `distro-info` package is `debian-distro-info`. We should respect Ubuntu parents :)

Answer (score 5):

Also a general way (works also on non-Ubuntu distros as well):

```
lsb_release -a
```

It uses `/etc/os-release` to read the config data. On .deb-based distros, also `/etc/dpkg` should correct as so. After a manual shift to/from Ubuntu, this should be manually corrected.